# Browsers ignoring protocol for relative paths

Tags: html, https

Sorry if this has come up before - I couldn't find anything to support what I seem to be experiencing at the moment.

I tend to use URL's like /art/img.png and /scripts/my.php for loading in content, whether it be by AJAX or a standard  tag.

However, I've just noticed that if I load https://dummy.com/ and that page contains a relative link to /myajax.php, it is loading http://dummy.com/myajax.php - and I can't tell if this is the expected behaviour or not?

If it helps, this only seems to be happening for XMLHTTPRequests, and I've seen it in Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 2):

That is not expected behaviour.

It is likely either:

1. a bug in some Ajax abstraction layer that you are using. (e.g. it might convert the relative URI to an absolute URI using `location.host` instead of letting the browser handle it)
2. a consequence of using the `<base>` element (which tells the browser to compute URIs relative to a different base URI)

Comment: I'm actually deliberately adding a <base> element in the <head> now, and looking at the console it's still whacking http in front of everything.

Also it looks like this is a jQuery bug then.